# German words with interesting etymology

Tags: etymology, big-list

Which German words have a very interesting etymological history?

Translation:

Welche deutschen Wörter haben eine besonders interessante etymologische Geschichte?

Comment: Is this on topic? "Interesting" is rather relative. This site is about opinion, not about facts or use of the language.

Comment: Voting to close as too subjective. [Related meta by OP](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/20/are-the-following-two-big-list-questions-posted-by-me-welcome-here)

Comment: I opened a meta thread:
http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/20/are-the-following-two-big-list-questions-posted-by-me-welcome-here

Comment: It is certainly too broad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word "Neanderthaler" comes from the cave in the valley "Neanderthal".

The word "Neanderthal" comes from the word Tal=valley in old spelling and the name of Neander, a composer of church hymns who lived near this valley.

The name "Neander" was the Greek version of the Neander's original name "Neumann" (neu (german) =new ( english) = neo (Greek), mann (german) = man (english) = andr- (Greek) )

So, the word Neanderthaler actually comes from a name meaning "new man".

Answer (score 3):

Das Wort 'Handy'. Viele Deutsche glauben, dass dieses Wort aus Englisch kommt. Das ist falsch! Es kommt eigentlich vom 'Handfunkgerät' (hand(held) radio-machine)!